# Change BarButtonItem Font Using Swift (Xcode 6)

Tags: xcode, swift, fonts, navigation, uinavigationbar

I am having trouble changing the font in my swift Xcode project of a BarButtonItem that was added to a navigation controller. I was able to change the color of the button without a problem, but the font will not change. Code:

```
var navTextColor = UIColor(red:0.3, green:0.09, blue:0.05, alpha:1.0)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = navTextColor
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you create and outlet (e.g. `@IBOutlet var barButton: UIBarButtonItem!`) linked to your `UIBarButtonItem`, you should be able to change your font type by using `setTitleTextAttributes` on the outlet.

```
barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

**Swift3**

```
barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12)!], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Comment: This changes the navigation bar text but not the text of the bar button items added to it.

Comment: Indeed. I edited my answer in order to change the font on the button itself

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

Another easy way to change all `TabBarItem`s font is using this code in `ViewDidLoad()` of `UITabBarController` : (No need to create an Outlet )

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "IranSansMobile", size: 15)!], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

```
barButton.setTitleTextAttributes([ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12)!], for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 12)!], for: .normal)
```